# Are there leftover files when I uninstall an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, applications

If I remove an app then will the preferences/caches/logs be deleted as wel?

Comment: I'm guessing not. Never seen anything mentioned about it before, and it seems big enough deal that someone would have put up a fuss about it somewhere. I am very curious to know (hopefully) some facts either way. Great question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, no files are leftover when deleting an app. iOS apps (and now  OS X  apps too), are **Sandboxed**. This means that each App has its own space in disk, with its own directories, which act as the home for the app and its data.

Deleting an app from the iPhone deletes this sandbox, deleting all data associated with the app.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was able to verify it with iFile. Indeed each app has its own Library folder etc.