# How do I uninstall an iOS app completely?

Tags: applications, ios, macos

I deleted and reinstalled a game on iOS. The app still knows my account name.

According to [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63162/are-there-leftover-files-when-i-uninstall-an-iphone-app) there are no leftovers when an app is deleted.

How it is possible that the app still knows my previous login name? How can I make it forget it?

Note: it's a gamecenter app. I also accepted the option to remove it from the gamecenter.

My device runs iOS 6.0.1 and is not jailbroken.

Answer (score 2):

Did the app know your account name when you installed it initially? Also, which game is it?

It is true that when you delete an app, it is completely removed from your device, and all settings are deleted. It is possible however that it still can identify your device and associate it with information its storing on its own servers.

Comment: The app is _Life is magic_. As it is a quite new app, I was under the impression that Apple wouldn't allow an app anymore to query the UDID. Is this correct? Are there other ways for an app to identify a device?

Comment: Perhaps Life is Magic has a record of what your Game Center name is, and when it recognizes that again, it knows it's you. It is possible for certain apps or websites (e.g. FreeMyApps) to get your UDID if you choose to allow it to install some setting on the device.

Comment: I don't think it's the Game Center name, on a different device with the same Game Center name I have a different account.

Comment: That's weird, it shouldn't be happening, because it really does delete apps fully. My only other guess is that when you open the game for the first time maybe it quickly loads Safari and saves a cookie. So try removing the game, clearing browsing data for Safari, and installing again. You can also ask the developer, Bad Robot Labs, at [their support desk](https://redrobotlabs.zendesk.com/anonymous_requests/new).